Need advice on voltage protection circuit
I am working on a schematic for a USB mux with multiple voltage input sources.
Voltage can come from USB-C (V_USB1) or a separate input source to a LDO (+5V).

When USB-C (V_USB1) is powered, the U5 usb mux select pin should stay high. When +5V is supplied, voltage shouldn't go through D4 to V_USB1, so that U5 select pin would stay low. From my limited knowledge, the Schottky diodes D1 and D4 that was chosen should protect voltage up to 10V, but I am getting 5 volts from (V_USB1) when only (+5V) is supplied. Am I missing anything here?


The first problem is it's likely that the voltage input is not turning the select pin into a high state:

If there is 5V from the usb, the diode will drop 0.2 to 0.4V (at least 1mA from the resistors, and possibly more up to 0.5V). So the resistor is seeing a voltage ~4.8V. Divide that in half from the 2.2k voltage divider and that is 2.4V. Barely enough to turn on the select pin, if you have any load on the usb 5V line, the select pin will never turn on.
There is no reason to use such a high current resistors as 2.2k, that puts a large load on the diode.
There is also a few things you could try that are easy, the first is using a large resitance for R14 and R15. 50k would be a good start. Measure the voltage across R15 and see if the select pin goes high.
Another thing is I would not imagine that the select pin would need to be protected with a diode, you could probably eliminate D8, this would also depend on the load.
Another thing worth mentioning is the output enable is not controlled, so the pins don't go to a high impedance state (on both usbs). You may want them to be high impedance.


Appreciate your response! From my understanding, the Vcc you highlighted is meant for the IC voltage supply. I am supplying 3.3V to the IC, hence the min voltage to set the pin high would be 1.3V. The issue I'm facing is not so much about the select pin being stuck, more of the diode D1 and D4 are not protecting reverse voltage as I expected them to. i.e. supplying voltage over (+5V) but I'm measuring 5V on (V_USB1) as well.

The highlight is a voltage input level, it has nothing to do with the supply
